# How to hide UILabel with viewWithTag?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, tags, uilabel

I want to hide UILabel but I am not able to hide my label outside the ViewDidLoad or "inside the ViewDidLoad but outside the for loop". In ViewDidLoad inside the for loop I can achieve what I want. I can hide the label with tag. But outside the loop it did not work.

This is what I am doing. Please have a look.

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{
int lbl_Pos_X = 580;

for (j=0; j<30; j++) {

    lbl = [[UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lbl_Pos_X, 21, 7, 15)];
    lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    lbl.tag = j;
    [self.view addSubview:lbl];
    //[lbl release];

    lbl_Pos_X = lbl_Pos_X + 5;


    [lbl viewWithTag:10].hidden = YES;  // here working
    }

     [lbl viewWithTag:12].hidden = YES;  // here  Not working

}
```

Any Idea or Suggestion would be highly welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using following code

```
[lbl viewWithTag:12].hidden = YES;
```

which sound incorrect because `viewWithTag` function return The view in the receiver’s hierarchy whose tag property matches the value in the tag parameter..

try as below in both the palaces (in or out of loop).

```
UILabel *label = [self.view viewWithTag:12];
label.hidded = YES;
```

Comment: I want to use this code but only for one label, is this possible? for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            subview.hidden = YES;
        }

Comment: yes, you can use but in if condition replace condition as
if(XX ==[_label1 tag]) where XX = tag no for the label you want to hide. because it seems you have more than one UILabels and you want to hide the specific one but if you want to hide all UILabel's than your code will work fine.

Comment: If I am giving viewWithTag:0  then all my ipad page got hidden. All the screen will become white. If I give  viewWithTag:1 then no problem but lbl.tag = 0; is become visible.

Comment: @NishaSingh obviously all views gets hide if you give  viewWithTag:0 because by default tag set to zero. so you should assign tag by yourself in interface builder to the label or any controls you want. than use that tag to hide that view or for any other option.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your label from its superview on which it has been added .

Replace your code with this :

```
 [self.view viewWithTag:12].hidden = YES;
```

**EDIT :** If you need to hide only one label for specific tag then use this :

```
  for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] && (view.tag == 12)) {
            [view setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
```

It will work for you.

Comment: It says Expression is not assignable.

Comment: check now. I have romoved UILabel typecasting. It was due to typecasting

Comment: If I am giving viewWithTag:0  then all my ipad page got hidden. All the screen will become white. If I give  viewWithTag:1 then no problem but lbl.tag = 0; is become visible.

Comment: I have updated my answer.  You can check class of the objecvt you need to hide. If it is lable then it will setisfy the TRUE condition and will hide label only not the images.

Comment: One Hint : Never try to assign tag 0 because this is the default tag assigned to all objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one..

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:12];
label.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: If I am giving viewWithTag:0  then all my ipad page got hidden. All the screen will become white. If I give  viewWithTag:1 then no problem but lbl.tag = 0; is become visible.

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt work because it is out of scope definition of lbl with valid memory.[inside if loop you are allocing it and hence have valid memory when the lbl with tag 10 exist there]

In here you have to get the  label from superview ,ie self.view and then use it

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:12];
```

and then make it hidden as

```
label.hidden=YES;
```

EDIT :viewWithTag:0 problem

It is because self.view has all views with tag value 0 since the default tag value is 0.What you should do is check weather the view returned is uilabel and tehn make it hidden,OR set up an unique tag value for all the label in the loop be changing the loop statement

Solution : Another way 
Keep an array with all the label reference ,you can use it anywhere you need later.
Declare

```
NSMutableArray *labelArray;
```

in viewDidLoad

```
{
    labelArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
    int lbl_Pos_X=0;

    for (int j=0; j<30; j++) {

       UILabel* lbl = [[UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lbl_Pos_X, 21, 7, 15)];
        lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        lbl.tag = j;
        [self.view addSubview:lbl];
        [labelArray addObject:lbl];
        //[lbl release];

        lbl_Pos_X = lbl_Pos_X + 5;


        [lbl viewWithTag:10].hidden = YES;  // here working
    }

    UILabel *label=[labelArray objectAtIndex:15];
    label.hidden=YES;
}
```

Comment: If I am giving viewWithTag:0  then all my ipad page got hidden. All the screen will become white. If I give  viewWithTag:1 then no problem but lbl.tag = 0; is become visible.

Comment: @NishaSingh : try this

Answer (score 1):

```
 [lbl viewWithTag:12].hidden = YES;
```

it not working out side for loop,out side for loop lbl is equal to nil,you not access directly label, like this `[lbl viewWithTag:12].hidden = YES;`, use identifier to access label like this

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:12];
```

Comment: If I am giving viewWithTag:0  then all my ipad page got hidden. All the screen will become white. If I give  viewWithTag:1 then no problem but lbl.tag = 0; is become visible.

Answer (score 1):

`viewWithTag:` sometimes behave unexpected. (if you view has hierarchical subviews)

To get rid of this, better to do something like this.

```
for (UIView *subview in parentViewOfLabel)
{
   if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] && [subview tag]==12)
      subview.hidden = YES;        
}
```

Make sure you are giving proper parent of label here.

Comment: You should `break;` the loop after hide the label.